# Show image in different view in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I have to code a model that one part of this model is done
on patches and turtles, and another part only display 
an image. I want to have these two parts in seperate 
view simultaneously.

For example, my model is that it creates 100 turtles with 
random xcor & ycor. I code that these turtles move around 
view in random path. Now, I want show an image in 
another seperate view and these two views (1. view of moving turtles 2. view of displaying an image) is displayed 
simultaneously. My problem is that how can I have two seperate
views in NetLogo.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you want doesn't really exist in NetLogo.

Not *really*. But check out https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Multiple-views-via-HubNet :

> Users often ask if they can have more than one view in their model and show different things, or show the same things differently, in each one.
>   Hopefully in the future we'll provide this capability directly. But it is already possible now using HubNet with local clients. It's a bit awkward, but it works. [...]